# How to resolve Openssl Package error while installing nginx

Tags: linux, nginx, yum, openssl, package-management

I tried to install nginx in a **RHEL 7.2 machine**, and i got an error,

```
Error: Package: 1:nginx-1.10.2-2.el7.x86_64 (epel)
       Requires: libcrypto.so.10(OPENSSL_1.0.2)(64bit)
You could try using --skip-broken to work around the problem
You could try running: rpm -Va --nofiles --nodigest
```

Nut this libcrypto.so.10(OPENSSL_1.0.2)(64bit) is not available on default openssl package so i removed the current openssl package and installed using rpm as below,

```
[root@db-brm ~]# rpm -Uvh http://mirror.centos.org/centos/7/os/x86_64/Packages/openssl-libs-1.0.2k-8.el7.x86_64.rpm
```

I thought it would solve the issue but it did not and it increase the conflict in openssl and giving error while installing nginx,

I could see this is the error,

```
[root@db-brm ~]# yum install nginx
Loaded plugins: langpacks, product-id, search-disabled-repos, subscription-manager
This system is not registered to Red Hat Subscription Management. You 
can use subscription-manager to register.
epel/x86_64/metalink                                                                                                                                       
|  16 kB  00:00:00     
local-repo                                                                                                                                                 
| 4.1 kB  00:00:00     
nginx                                                                                                                                                      
| 2.9 kB  00:00:00     
Resolving Dependencies
--> Running transaction check
---> Package nginx.x86_64 1:1.12.2-1.el7_4.ngx will be installed
--> Processing Dependency: openssl >= 1.0.2 for package: 1:nginx-1.12.2-1.el7_4.ngx.x86_64
--> Running transaction check
---> Package openssl.x86_64 1:1.0.1e-42.el7_1.9 will be installed
--> Processing Dependency: openssl-libs(x86-64) = 1:1.0.1e-42.el7_1.9 for package: 1:openssl-1.0.1e-42.el7_1.9.x86_64
--> Finished Dependency Resolution
Error: Package: 1:openssl-1.0.1e-42.el7_1.9.x86_64 (local-repo)
       Requires: openssl-libs(x86-64) = 1:1.0.1e-42.el7_1.9
       Installed: 1:openssl-libs-1.0.2k-8.el7.x86_64 (installed)
           openssl-libs(x86-64) = 1:1.0.2k-8.el7
       Available: 1:openssl-libs-1.0.1e-42.el7_1.9.x86_64 (local-repo)
           openssl-libs(x86-64) = 1:1.0.1e-42.el7_1.9
You could try using --skip-broken to work around the problem
You could try running: rpm -Va --nofiles --nodigest
```

***Can anyone help me to solve this issue?***

Comment: I assume you have your NginX repository set up properly? If you aren't then try adding it to /etc/yum.repos.d/nginx.repo. See if it installs then.

Comment: There could be another issue. Your `openssl-libs` could be newer that `openssl` depends. So you could remove `openssl-libs`, make `yum clean all` and install `nginx`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Quote from NGINX forums [Ref](https://forum.nginx.org/read.php?2,276398,276796#msg-276796)

> Unfortunately there is only one solution - get the systems upgraded to 7.4; one should also keep in mind that 7.0-7.3 are not supported by the distributions vendors anymore (including security fixes)

However, you could install NGINX from source see, [stack exchange](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/275211/how-to-update-openssl-on-centos-7-2)

```
sudo yum install unzip gcc pcre-devel zlib-devel make golang wget
mkdir -p /tmp/nginx-dep
cd /tmp/nginx-dep
curl -O https://www.openssl.org/source/openssl-1.0.2g.tar.gz
curl -O http://nginx.org/download/nginx-1.9.14.tar.gz
tar zxf openssl-1.0.2g.tar.gz
tar zxf nginx-1.9.14.tar.gz
cd nginx-1.9.14/
./configure --with-http_ssl_module \
            --with-openssl=`realpath ../openssl-1.0.2g` \
            --prefix=/usr/share/nginx \
            --sbin-path=/usr/sbin/nginx \
            --modules-path=/usr/lib/nginx/modules \
            --conf-path=/etc/nginx/nginx.conf \
            --error-log-path=/var/log/nginx/error.log \
            --http-log-path=/var/log/nginx/access.log \
            --pid-path=/run/nginx.pid \
            --lock-path=/var/lock/nginx.lock \
            --http-client-body-temp-path=/var/lib/nginx/body \
            --http-fastcgi-temp-path=/var/lib/nginx/fastcgi \
            --http-proxy-temp-path=/var/lib/nginx/proxy \
            --http-scgi-temp-path=/var/lib/nginx/scgi \
            --http-uwsgi-temp-path=/var/lib/nginx/uwsgi \
            --with-openssl-opt=enable-ec_nistp_64_gcc_128 \
            --with-openssl-opt=no-nextprotoneg \
            --with-openssl-opt=no-weak-ssl-ciphers \
            --with-openssl-opt=no-ssl3 \
            --with-pcre-jit \
            --with-threads \
            --with-http_addition_module \
            --with-http_auth_request_module \
            --with-http_dav_module \
            --with-http_flv_module \
            --with-http_gunzip_module \
            --with-http_gzip_static_module \
            --with-http_mp4_module \
            --with-http_random_index_module \
            --with-http_realip_module \
            --with-http_slice_module \
            --with-http_ssl_module \
            --with-http_sub_module \
            --with-http_stub_status_module \
            --with-http_v2_module \
            --with-http_secure_link_module \
            --with-mail \
            --with-mail_ssl_module \
            --with-stream \
            --with-stream_ssl_module
make
sudo make install

sudo mkdir -p /var/lib/nginx && sudo nginx -t

# create service
sudo touch /etc/systemd/system/nginx.service
printf '
[Unit]
Description=The nginx HTTP and reverse proxy server
After=network.target remote-fs.target nss-lookup.target

[Service]
Type=forking
PIDFile=/run/nginx.pid
# Nginx will fail to start if /run/nginx.pid already exists but has the wrong
# SELinux context. This might happen when running `nginx -t` from the cmdline.
# https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=1268621
ExecStartPre=/usr/bin/rm -f /run/nginx.pid
ExecStartPre=/usr/sbin/nginx -t
ExecStart=/usr/sbin/nginx
ExecReload=/bin/kill -s HUP $MAINPID
KillSignal=SIGQUIT
TimeoutStopSec=5
KillMode=process
PrivateTmp=true

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target' | sudo tee  /etc/systemd/system/nginx.service

rm /tmp/nginx-dep -ri
```

Comment: Thanks a lot... Nginx works on port 8080, but service seems not up.. [root@db-brm nginx-1.9.14]# systemctl status nginx
● nginx.service - The nginx HTTP and reverse proxy server
   Loaded: loaded (/etc/systemd/system/nginx.service; enabled; vendor preset: disabled)
   Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Sun 2017-12-03 01:14:52 IST; 2min 8s ago
  Process: 10565 ExecStart=/usr/sbin/nginx (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)
  Process: 10563 ExecStartPre=/usr/sbin/nginx -t (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
  Process: 10561 ExecStartPre=/usr/bin/rm -f /run/nginx.pid (code=exited, status=0/

Comment: What's the output of this? `systemctl status nginx.service`